# Initializer rspec test passing, but actual code breaks when tested manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have an initializer in Model:

```
def initialize(user=nil, attributes={})
  @user = user      
  indifferent_access_attributes = attributes.with_indifferent_access
  (self.class.seller_fields & indifferent_access_attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym)).each do |field|
    seller[field] = indifferent_access_attributes[field]
  end
  validate!
end
```

#### Rspec Model Validation Test

Then I create a new model and test if its valid, it passes:

```
  values = {"has_style"=>"1234", "color"=>"black"}
  cr = CarRegistration::seller.new(@user, values)
  cr.valid?
  expect(cr.errors[f]).to include("can't be blank")
```

However, it should not as I get an error when tested manually:

> undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for  ActionController::Parameters:0x00007facc67ef980

Originally, I added the   `indifferent_access_attributes = attributes.with_indifferent_access`
code because my rspec tests were failing, but the manual tests were working. Now the manual tests fail and the rspec test work.

I assume it is that my model sees the parameters as parameters when the server passes them in, and my model sees it as a hash from the rspec test . How do I keep my test and the server consistent and test parameters from in rspec? Also, how do I fix my error.

### Summary

To clarify even more: my rspec test passes `values` as a hash class and when I manually test, a parameter class gets passed. How do I pass a parameters class in rspec instead of a hash class?

Comment: did you put the values declaration on the line above your initialize call?

Comment: yes, the value declaration works for the validation. please read my last paragraph per the issue.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is check to make sure you're calling the right class constructor. Why is your `seller` class not camel case?

Comment: if you want to be consistent you should use `ActionController::Parameters` instead of a hash in your test. but that still doesn't explain why your test isn't failing